# How can I check from bash whether my desktop is locked?

Tags: bash, systemd, xorg, kde, session

For use in shell scripts and ssh. I need something to tell me whether my desktop screen/session is locked.

I'm using KDE, Xorg and systemd.

Comment: There are numerous ways how sceens are locked. Best is to wait for a sceenlock and then analyze the syslog for the actual locking command in use. Check this listing for common methods [-> archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Session_lock)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver GetActive
```